# Pointing multiple Heroku apps (each app React+Node) to a specific address with backslashes (/)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, dns, heroku-cli

We have 3 domains in Heroku

https://digitalbazuka-employees.herokuapp.com/

https://digitalbazuka-clients.herokuapp.com/

https://digitalbazuka-admins.herokuapp.com/

Each one of them is a NODE JS (server) and React App (client).

What I want is to make:

1. `https://digitalbazuka-clients.herokuapp.com/` to be the app that starts 
   when the user type `https://digitalbazuka.com/`
2. `https://digitalbazuka-employees.herokuapp.com/` would be accessed through : 
   `https://digitalbazuka.com/employees`
3. `https://digitalbazuka-admins.herokuapp.com/` would be accessed through : 
   `https://digitalbazuka.com/admins`

Is it possible to do it ? How ?

Answer (score 1):

Either a reverse proxy or using something like Cloudflare page rules for redirects.

Comment: What about custom subdomains ? would it help ?

Comment: doing cname DNS records for your subdomains is easy.  Just map `digitalbazuka-admins.herokuapp.com/` to `admins.digitalbazuka.com` for example.  Then a lot of DNS providers will allow you to create custom redirects to paths on your domain.  This is a not a feature of all DNS providers, though, so you'll have to find one that does.

Comment: Heroku doesn't allow me to change `digitalbazuka-admins.herokuapp.com/` to `admins.digitalbazuka.com`

Comment: You need to change your DNS to reflect this - not at Heroku.  Wherever your DNS records are kept (possibly with your domain registrar), you need to create a CNAME record and point `admins.digitalbazuka.com` to `digitalbazuka-admins.herokuapp.com`.